# Word for lights on police cars, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

Police cars or ambulances have lights on their roof, which are on when the sirens are on. What are these lights called? Is it something like **signal lights** or **alarm lights**?

I am looking for an official term/word.

Example sentence:

> ……………… create an interesting atmosphere at night.

Comment: Are you looking for the term specific to a mounted lightbar, or any form of similar warning lights.  For example, unmarked police cars may have them hidden somewhere, like behind the grill, and when a private vehicle is used, they may stick a portable warning light on the dashboard or on the roof with a magnet.  Those wouldn't be called a lightbar, they would be referred to by a more generic term.

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree that there would be a more generic term. However, OP specified *lights on the roof*, which I believe refers only to the lightbar.

Comment: @fixer1234: yes, any form of warning lights, also the portable ones you mentioned.

Comment: When I was a kid police cars were referred to as "cherry tops".  Of course, this was when they had a single red rotating beacon on top.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you are looking for the word "beacon lights".

An excerpt from Wikipedia

> **Vehicular beacons are rotating or flashing lights affixed to the top of a vehicle to attract the attention of surrounding vehicles and pedestrians. Emergency vehicles such as fire engines, ambulances, police cars, tow trucks, construction vehicles, and snow-removal vehicles carry beacon lights**

Here is a picture of such a light (Source: http://www.thehindubusinessline.com)

[image: Beacon light in a police car]

Comment: Beacon is the right word, @Harmless Psycho: 'light bar' refers to a more specific form-factor and you can note that the definition of 'light bar' in that answer contains the word 'beacon.'

Comment: Beacon is still used in UK legislation, even though almost all UK emergency vehicles use LED or strobe lights. But it's not a term in common use.

Answer (score 7):

The official term is [**lightbar/light bar**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/lightbar#p8gk0mvGDvhMJ69W.99)

> (noun) A bar mounted on the roof of a vehicle, such as a police car, with rotating beacons or other lights to provide a visual warning.

It is also labeled as such on the Merriam-Webster Visual Dictionary Online.
[image]

(Source: http://www.visualdictionaryonline.com/society/safety/crime-prevention/police-car.php)

---

A generic term for these lights seems to just be "Emergency vehicle lights." I have looked for a more specialised word, but even [websites that sell these lights](https://www.speedtechlights.com) refer to them as such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you also have an idea for a more generic term, which would include portable lights like described by fixer1234? I think some of those portable forms also can be applied on the roof.

Answer (score 4):

Police officers in the United States refer to them as *overheads*. Here's an example usage from an article on officer safety by [Shawm Perron, in Calibre Press](https://www.calibrepress.com/2016/07/mindful-officer-aware/):

> - *How about every time you activate your overheads? There are literally thousands of cues or triggers you can use to help you
>   practice mindfulness.*

And one more from an article on high-speed pursuits by [Sgt. Glenn French, in Police1](https://www.police1.com/officer-safety/articles/unintended-consequences-of-a-hypothetical-police-pursuit-BJyiWYmQW9c6jnVC/):

> - *You activate your overheads. The wagon shows no signs of slowing, so you activate your sirens. The vehicle is still not stopping, and by
>   now you’ve rolled through two more intersections as the suspect’s
>   vehicle accelerates.*

It's used [here](https://mdshooters.com/showthread.php?t=197615) as a heading in a post on traffic stop tactics.

Comment: I've adjusted the first quote. We might get arrested if we don't attribute correctly! (And I don't think anyone uses a comma before an italicised emphasis (_overheads_) nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

***Blues and twos** create an interesting atmosphere at night.*

Although British, and arguably informal, *blues and twos* refers to the lights and sirens together.

> blues and twos
> NOUN
>
> British  informal
> 1 The flashing lights and siren used on a police car or other emergency vehicle when responding to an incident. Also later "on (also under) blues and twos".
> 2 The emergency services (frequently the police).
>
> Origin.
> 1980s; earliest use found in Autocar. From the plural of blue + the plural of two, with reference to the blue flashing lights and (typically) two-tone siren used on an emergency vehicle.
> — [O-D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blues_and_twos)